# PowerShellからプロジェクトのビルドができない

Tags: visual-studio, powershell

PowerShell上からソリューション内の指定のプロジェクトを
VisualStudio.DTEを介してビルドしたいのですが
うまくいきません
おそらくソリューション内のソリューションフォルダの階層を潜る必要があると思うのですが
方法がわからないです

ソリューションの構成は以下です
Solutionフォルダ
│ └─Project1フォルダ
│ │     └─Project.csproj
│ │  
│ └─Project2フォルダ
│　     └─Projec2.csproj
│
└─Solution.sln
└─Build.ps1

以下コードです

```
$VSDTE=New-Object -ComObject VisualStudio.DTE
$VSDTE.MainWindow.Visible=$True
$VSDTE.Solution.Open("$PSScriptRoot\○○○○.sln")
foreach($prj in $VSDTE.Solution.Projects)
{
    // ここで階層を潜りたい
    $VSDTE.Solution.SolutionBuild.BuildProject("Release", $prj.UniqueName, $true)
}

$VSDTE.Quit()
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($VSDTE)
```

参考
[MicroSoft Docs EnvDTE Namespace](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/envdte?view=visualstudiosdk-2017)

Comment: Visual Studioは内部的には[MSBuild](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild?view=vs-2019)を呼び出しているだけなので、COMを使うより直接MSBuildを起動するのはダメなんでしょうか？

Comment: おっしゃる通りなのですが今回は共同で開発していて資材生成用にビルドを自動化したく、MSBuildのパスの違いを考えてCOMを使っています

Comment: ちなみに「うまくいきません」とはどんな現象やエラーメッセージになるのでしょうか？

Comment: 質問からは外れますが、[vswhere](https://github.com/microsoft/vswhere) を使えばMSBuildのパスを取得できます。ご参考まで。

Answer (score 0):

> 質問からは外れますが、vswhere を使えばMSBuildのパスを取得できます。ご参考まで。 – nee 2日前

今回はこちらで対応することにしました
皆さんご回答ありがとうございました